# Проверка всех TextBox'ов на пустоту

Tags: c#, textbox

На GroupBox расположены TextB и СомboB как проверить их разом на заполненость(пустоту) и изменить цвет пустых?
Хотя бы текстбоксы, комбо не принципиально.
Заранее спасибо!☺☻

Comment: что значит "пустой комбобокс"?

Comment: После редактирования вопроса, мой ответ стал малорелевантным. :( Всё же следует задавать отдельный вопрос в таком случае.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо)) Все гуд )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool allEmpty = true;
bool someEmpty = false;

foreach(TextBox textBox in groupBox.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()) 
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
  {
    someEmpty = true; 
    textBox.BackColor = Color.Red;
  }
  else
    allEmpty = false;
}

if (!someEmpty)
{
  // ВСЕ боксы не пусты, выполнять код на добавление в БД
}
```

Comment: Спасибо пашет!
Как теперь поменять цвет тех текстбоксов что пусты?

Comment: @ne0n внеси дополнение в вопрос хотя бы...

Comment: @ne0n Вы прочитали код в ответе или только скопировали )? Условие `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))` что-нибудь Вам говорит?

Comment: @Igor я понял где прописать, просто если конкретный текстбокс то я знаю как textbox1.backcolor = color.red, а все как? не догоняю, извините если туплю

Comment: @ne0n переменная `textBox` внутри цикла - это конкретный `TextBox`

Comment: @Igor Спасибо большущие!!! Герой ☻☺

Comment: @ne0n На здоровье. Успехов!

Comment: @Igor можете еще подсказать.
Короче мне надо, когда ВСЕ боксы не пусты, выполнять код на добавление в БД, я запихал свой код в ветку else и когда все боксы пусты все норм, но если хотя бы 1 бокс не пуст, то добавляет в БД пустые ТБ.
Выручите?

Comment: @ne0n Это надо делать *после* цикла - см. добавление в ответе.

Comment: @Igor записал в **Foreach**, работает. спасибо)

Answer (score 3):

```
bool allEmpty = groupBox.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().All(tb => tb.Text == string.Empty);
```