# Изменение цвета Checkbox и сохранение после перезапуска

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

День добрый, как реализовать чтобы выделенные чекбоксы после нажатия на "Красный" или "Зеленый" приобретали данные цвета и сохраняли их при перезапуске программы?

Comment: Можно сохранять конечные состояния в файл в любом удобном вам формате. Я бы выбрал XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы же понимаете, что у вас несколько вопросов?

1. Как изменить цвет. (что было [задано](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/828745/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%85-textbox%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83) буквально пару часов назад)
2. Как сохранить - что по сути является довольно обширным вопросом...

---

Но так уж и быть, натолкну вас на нужный путь.

1. Как изменить... Тут нам нужен некий метод, который будет менять цвет на нужный нам. Я лично подпишу 2 кнопки (красная и зеленая) на 1 обработчик события Click. В нем я получу имя кнопки (у меня они RedBtn и GreenBtn), по имени буду задавать переменной цвет. Далее с помощью Linq я получу все контролы, тип которых CheckBox, из них выберу те, что были выбраны, ну и пройдусь циклом по ним для изменения цвета у каждого элемента. Весь код будет у нас тогда таким:

   ```
   private void ColorBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       var btn = sender as Button;
       var color = btn?.Name == "RedBtn" ? Color.Red : Color.Green;

       Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
           .Where(x=>x.Checked)
           .ToList()
           .ForEach(x=>x.ForeColor = color);
   }
   ```

Запускаем и проверяем:

[image: Result]

Тут стоит отметить то, что данный код берет все контролы окна (что не есть хорошо), по этому их желательно сгруппировать в какую нибудь Panel, тогда нам нужно будет производить поиск только по панели (`panel1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()...`).

2. Сохранение... Тут очень общий вопрос, каждый сохраняет так, как ему захочется, зависит все от проекта и предпочтений. Я обычно использую JSON, кто то любит XML, а кто то использует стандартные методы записи настроек. Выберите то, что вам больше подходит и сохраняйте туда нужные вам данные.

Comment: Можете еще подсказать, как присвоить значение матрице через чекбокс? Матрица 3х4 и каждое значение присваивать выбранным чекбоксам ( которые соответствуют матрице) при помощи кнопки "+1". –

Comment: @ВикторПрокопенко На данном ресурсе принято задавать один вопрос за раз. Пожалуйста, задайте то, что вы хотите отдельным вопросом и как можно подробнее его опишите. Также не забудьте приложить свои наработки.

Comment: Ну к сожалению смогу задать следующий вопрос через пару дней, так что спросил как мог...

Answer (score 1):

Правый клик по проекту -> Свойства, создаем под каждый чекбокс свойство, как на картинке
[image: создание свойств для сохранения конфигурации приложения]

далее что-то такое

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ReadColorCheckBoxes();
    }

    private void buttonGreen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetBackColorCheckBoxes(Color.Green);
        SaveColorCheckBoxes();
    }

    private void buttonRed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetBackColorCheckBoxes(Color.Red);
        SaveColorCheckBoxes();
    }

    private void SetBackColorCheckBoxes(Color color)
    {
        var checkboxes = GetCheckedCheckBoxes();

        foreach (var checkbox in checkboxes)
        {
            checkbox.BackColor = color;
        }
    }

    private void SaveColorCheckBoxes()
    {
        var checkboxes = GetCheckedCheckBoxes();

        foreach (var checkbox in checkboxes)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default[checkbox.Name] = checkbox.BackColor;
        }

        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }

    private void ReadColorCheckBoxes()
    {
        foreach (var checkbox in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
        {
            checkbox.BackColor = (Color)Properties.Settings.Default[checkbox.Name];
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<CheckBox> GetCheckedCheckBoxes()
    {
        return this.Controls
                            .OfType<CheckBox>()
                            .Where(c => c.Checked == true);
    }
}
```